# Jenkins 502 Gateway error for organization folder

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have Jenkins pipeline with many freestyle pipeline, normal pipeline and Organization folder where actual deployment pipeline placed. Most of the time all pipelines are working properly but only Organization folder is getting stuck and showes 502 Gateway error, in same pipeline all of the pipelines are working fine.

Need suggestion to troubleshoot.